# How to read csv dataset using shell command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function, shell

In my repository I had a shell file get_data.sh with this kind of command:

```
wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt \
"https://docs.google.com/u.... \
'https://docs.google.com/...." \
-O train.tar.gz && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt && \
tar -zxvf train.tar.gz && rm -rf train.tar.gz
```

I want to read train.csv file in my python code using that shell file. How could I do that? How to run that file and than read train.csv from it in python code? Thanks in advance

How should a command in python look like to run shell file which is in same project?

Comment: have you tried panads read csv?

Comment: @Goion what do you mean? with which file? I  have only shell file

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/646876/pass-filename-from-bash-to-python You might be looking for this. After you unzip the file, pass it to python to read it

Answer (score 0):

if I got you right you want to start a sub-process from your script. The documentation propose the following in such cases :

> The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the run()
> function for all use cases it can handle. For more advanced use cases,
> the underlying Popen interface can be used directly.

For more information look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) or [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Good luck!